# Switch from encrypted partition to unencrypted (Error: cryptsetup: evms_activate is not available)

Tags: boot, mount, grub2, encrypted-partition, luks

I initially installed Ubuntu 11.04 with an encrypted file system (from the alternate install CD: Guided Partitioning, LVM encrypted). Now I wanted to change this setup to have my root file system on an **unencrypted** partition.

I had the following setup before:

```
/dev/mapper/my-root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=0,commit=0)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,noatime)
```

- I backed up `/`, reformatted /dev/sda5 (which had contained the encrypted LVM device) to an ext3 partition, and restored `/` to that partition.
- I edited /etc/fstab, removed the line `/dev/mapper/my-root / ...`, and added the line: `/dev/sda5   /  ext3  noatime,rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0   0  1`
- I edited /etc/crypttab, and commented out the single entry.

On reboot, I get the grub screen as usual, but then I get the message `cryptsetup:evms_activate is not available`, `waiting for encrypted source device`.

I tried reinstalling Grub2 using a LiveCD with the [ChRoot method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#ChRoot), but that didn't make any difference.

Why is Ubuntu still searching for an encrypted device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow "fixed" it - however, I don't know for sure, which of the following actions was responsible:

I [chrooted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#ChRoot) again, then I ran

```
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic

update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda 
      (these last two steps I had already done before without success)
```

Also, I completely removed /etc/crypttab now (previously, I had only commented the line).

The error is gone now, but I would prefer to accept an answer which explains what happened here, and how to solve the problem a little bit less "chaotically" :-)

Comment: Fixing /etc/crypttab was the key!